# Sharing a Android library between Android App and Google AppEngine

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, javabeans

I have this Android App developing in Android Studio. Everything going great.
I add an AppEngine backend module in Android Studio. Everything still great.

Since I sometimes have to share objects (mostly simple JavaBeans) between my App and the AppEngine backend (think searching functions parameters, sending updated object, etc), I decided to create a shared library that both App and Backend can import, so they both reference the same Objects and interaction is simpler.

Some of my objects use Android specific functions such as Parcelable and other features that *cannot* be removed from the objects.

I create a simple "Android Library" in Android Studio and place all my Objects into this folder.
I set this new "Android Library" with all my objects as Dependency of my Android App and everything there works fine in the App build.

At this point I run head first into a wall.
I attempt to set the "Android Library" as a Dependency of the Backend and things go sideways.
When I attempt to build, I get the message that the Backend gradle build could not find the only Android related dependency I need *in the "Android Library"*. (So not a dependency I need in the Backend, but one needed and already existing in the "Android Library". The dependency was "appcompat-v7.)

So no matter what I do, the build says that it needs this dependency and that it cannot be found in neither a jcenter address or mavenCentral address. But the "Android Library" build is easily retrieving and building the dependency.

So my question is two-fold:
1. Can an Android Library be shared with AppEngine?
2. If it can, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the common code into another Maven/Gradle project (not Android library), install it to your local maven repository, and add it as dependency of both projects.

Comment: But since the common code is dependent on a small part of the Android platform, I would have to somehow "extract" those parts as well, which is impossible.

Comment: If that's the case I recommend rethinking the design. The common library should not depend on either GAE or Android. It's not just about design, things can really go wrong or not work at all when a "special" runtime tries to load/run code that's not meant for it. Don't be deterred by some code duplication if that's necessary. Extract what's possible (code that's not dependent on either environment) and duplicate the rest. Maybe look into code generation options if you need to have semi-duplicate code (like GAE Cloud Endpoints code generation).

Comment: I appreciate your answer and time.
I have thought along the same lines as you have suggested and will try to do as you say. Extract what can be extracted and leave the rest in a Android shared library only.